# Javascript multiple cookies banner

Tags: javascript, cookies

I know it may sound like a silly question, but I don't know how to do it.
I made a cookie banner in Javascript. So a simple banner where the user can accept or reject cookies, and once received, the banner disappears.
Here everything works fine, and saving cookies works.
But I was wondering how to go about making a banner like this:
[image]

How does this banner technically work, and how does it manage cookies?
I have not found anything about it, so I assume it works like the "traditional" banner (accept all or refuse).
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by sending to your server the preferences and the server will know which cookies to set